# Dashed horizontal line

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make a horizontal dashed line. Something to look like this:

[image: Dashed line from iOS]

This is how I do this in iOS:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

CGSize frameSize = size;

CGRect shapeRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, frameSize.width, frameSize.height);
[shapeLayer setBounds: shapeRect];
[shapeLayer setPosition: CGPointMake(frameSize.width / 2, frameSize.height / 2)];

[shapeLayer setFillColor: [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[shapeLayer setStrokeColor: color];
[shapeLayer setLineWidth: 3.0f];
[shapeLayer setLineJoin: kCALineJoinRound];
[shapeLayer setLineDashPattern: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 10], [NSNumber numberWithInt: 5], nil]];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: shapeRect cornerRadius: 0];
[shapeLayer setPath: path.CGPath];
```

How to achieve a similar effect in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**// UPDATE ANSWER 2**

we can approach that by java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
 
public class MyView extends View {
 
 Paint paint;
 Path path;
 
 public MyView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  init();
 }
 
 public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  init();
 }
 
 public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  init();
 }
 
 private void init() {
  paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
  paint.setStrokeWidth(10); // set stroke value as you want
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 
   

  
   
  float[] intervals = new float[]{50.0f, 20.0f};
  float phase = 0;
   
  DashPathEffect dashPathEffect = 
    new DashPathEffect(intervals, phase);
 
  paint.setPathEffect(dashPathEffect);
 
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);
path = new Path(); // this method to make path for our draw 
      path.moveTo(50, 50);  // x , y value of start point , if you dont any value the default will be (0,0)
      path.lineTo(50, 500); // to (x,y) value end point  use getMeasuredWidth() to full width in x value
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
 
 }
 
}
```

to use it in your application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<view
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.imaadv.testpro.DashedLineView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My Android 4.1.2 displayed it as a solid ~1px-tall line…

Comment: I update my answer please check it , you can change image view height to draw dashed line in good way

Comment: A bit better but now I see two dashed lines (top one is thicker, bottom one is thinner).

Comment: you can change android:width="1dp" to any width you like , but dont forget adapt it with image view height

Comment: I didn't change anything, I just used your example…

Comment: I think the older versions of Android don't support drawing dashed lines on a hardware layer. Try calling  setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE) on your custom View.

Comment: what is the version do you use ?

Comment: I am testing on 4.1.2.

Comment: I needed to tweak it a little and to change `path` to `path.moveTo(0, 0); path.lineTo(getMeasuredWidth(), 0);` (before that change it was vertical instead of horizontal) but it finally works! Thanks!